# Write a new line to a web site using System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in C#

Tags: c#, printing, web

I'm trying to write some text to a website using the System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode function in C#. The string parameter that I give to the function has some Environment.Newline's in it, but they are not written out on the website. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More detail needed. What does "write some text to a website" mean? Are you writing an html page to be displayed over the web, or posting some data to a web site for processing? You do know that newlines are treated as white space when rendering html web pages, and to get an actual new line you need to insert markup (e.g. <br>)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not know that. I tried replacing the Environment.Newline's with "<br />"'s, but all I got was the "<br />"'s as part of the string. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newline is written out as a physical line break so you will have to either wrap in a pre:

```
response.Write("<pre>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str) + "</pre>");
```

Or replace the new line with a BR AFTER you have HtmlEncoded (or it'll encode the BR as well):

```
response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str).Replace("\n", "<br />"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is the response object you are referring to?

Comment: The line of code that I'm currently using is: HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message).Replace("\n", "<br />"); but its not printing anything out. The one I was using before was : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message, httpContext.Response.Output); and that printed out the text without the newlines. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ok I see.  This should work then instead: Response.Output.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message).Replace("\n", "<br />"))

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have an object that I can use in place of Response. Should I have such an object?

Comment: Sorry misread - I need to pay more attention! :)  Use: httpContext.Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message).Replace("\n", "<br />"))

Answer (score 1):

Given its HTML NewLine characters do not display as whitespace. Try replacing your new line characters with `<br/>` elements.